# Setting a value to a bootstrap date type textbox in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having difficulty binding my datetime data type bootstrap textbox of date type.  Below is my model.

```
  public class EmployeeApplications
    {
    ....
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime ApplicationDate { get; set; }
        public long UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

I strongly bound my model to a view with ApplicationDate property bound to a date type textbox below.

```
@Html.TextBox("ApplicationDate",String.Format("{0:d}", @p.ApplicationDate.ToShortDateString()),new { @class = "form-control datecontrol", @type = "date"  })
```

My problem is my date textbox isn't displaying the selected date returned by the ApplicationDate. I tried many things all failed. I stumbled upon a tutorial [here](http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/WebDevelopment/MVC/DatePickerMVC5.aspx) and tried with the his example. All failed. Please how do i set the value ? what do i do wrong ?

Comment: What is `p` in `@p.ApplicationDate.ToShortDateString()`? This suggests you must be doing something wrong (are you doing something in a loop?). The following will work `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDate, "{0:d}", ,new { @class ...})` and is the correct way to define the format string. Also are you wanting the HTML5 datepicker or are you using a jquery plugin?. For the HTML5 datepicke you need a different solution

Comment: @StephenMuecke . The example i saw was based on html5 datepicker. I am trying to implement Html5 Datepicker for it looks non complex here http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/WebDevelopment/MVC/DatePickerMVC5.aspx

Comment: It needs to be `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and add `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" ApplyInEditMode = true)]`, (ISO format) then `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDate, new { @class = "form-control datecontrol", type = "date" })` or you could remove both attributes and just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control datecontrol", type = "date" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke. Thank you sir. It works perfect now. Also I realized my  js wasn't loading and therefore affecting the working in IE . Now it works fine. Please write your answer will accept it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the HTML5 the date must be formatted in ISO format (yyyy-MM-dd).

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control datecontrol", type = "date" })
```

Side notes:

1. `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` is only applicable when using
   `Html.EditorFor()`, in which case you could also add the display
   format using `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" ApplyInEditMode = true)]` and generate the control using
   `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDate)`, however only MVC 5.1+
   supports adding html attributes (i.e. the bootstrap class names) so
   for MVC 4, it is necessary to use `Html.TextBoxFor()`
2. The HTML5 datepicker control is only supported in modern browsers
   and not yet at all in FireFox.

Comment: sir if you are available can you please see this angular js issue for me ? have being struggling with it since yest and couldnt get it going. all see fine yet my template not returning. I am confused :( http://goo.gl/KtKMpa

Comment: @NuruSalihu, Sory but I don't use angular so cant help

Comment: oh ok thank you for your time sir. I just couldnt integrate the angular . Its returning empty . I would have troubleshoot if there is an error . But couldnt even get started. Its frustrating . I am running node, express with angular on jade html engine . So far the angular template is returning empty .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".datecontrol").datepicker("update", new Date());
```

Comment: thank you. It does not change . will keep trying and see if i would understand though.

Answer (score 0):

For someone might not assign format and debug for hours like me, you can take a look about the format the bootstrap show. And set the format it needs.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt}", new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker"})
```

And my javascript call this function without format

```
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```